# Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'byte?[]' in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

My given code has an error of type conversion:

```
                byte?[] AibAttachment = null; 
                MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                AibAttachment = target.ToArray();
```

In above code AibAttachment = target.ToArray(); this line is throwing an error like "Cannot implicitly convert 'byte[]' to 'byte?[]'"

Please help me on this.

Comment: An `Array<byte>` is not the same as an `Array<Nullable<byte>>`, one can hold null values, the other can't.  You probably just want `byte[] AibAttachment = null;` instead. Even better, just `var AibAttachment = target.ToArray();`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Ok but I have to pass this byte array to some third party API and that AibAttachment variable is part of that API request which is of type byte?[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer with Linq:

```
byte[] original = null; // something 
byte?[] AibAttachment =  original.Select(a => (byte?) a).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
AibAttachment = Array.ConvertAll(target.ToArray(), i => (byte?)i);
```